# Make electron app components reusable

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am building an **Electron** desktop app which is of course based on node.js. Igot my toolchain ready and the dummy app building, but starting with the specific design of the app I  am asking myself how to split up the contents in different files to reuse them:

Imagine having some kind of header and footer bar that is supposed to be on every "page" of the electron app. The main content is of course supposed to change. **How can I organize my app to make the code for header and footer reusable?**

node.js' `require("some.js")` includes a javascript file, but I don't want to write HTML parts of the components in javascript...

Trying to use something like `$('#content').load("welcome.html");` didn't work out well because of the javascript and less files being included in the `welcome.html` respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can use various ways to templatize the html.

```
<tpl id="tplForComponentA">
  <div>something component A will use as a templete</div>
</tpl>
```

and on page load you can collect the tpl.innerHTML and use them where you need.

**Example**

```
//$('#content').load("welcome.html");
$('#content').html($('#tplForComponentA').html());
```

Comment: This does not answer any of my questions. How can I use this with electron? How would a possible file structure look like?

Comment: you said you don't want to write parts of html in js, right? You have a html file where the js is loaded, right? Use what I described to keep the html parts you need in the html file and add a mechanism to retrieve the needed html content from there in the js side.

Comment: And how would this work with something like angular.js?

Comment: Read here: https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/3354046 but instead of using the allTemplate.html declare them in index.html as well.